# Preview chrashes on certain page of pgfplots manual

Tags: pdf, preview

Howdy its quite known among [TeXies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) that under MacOSX the [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) manual brings Preview down on certain pages (with a lot of 3D content). Heres the (significant part of ) the log.

My question is: which one of the functions (classes, whatever) listed below is responsible for the crash and is there anything i can do to stop preview form crashing when comming to a bug in the pdfkit?

```
Process:         Preview 
Path:            /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
Identifier:      com.apple.Preview
Version:         5.0.3 (504.1)
Build Info:      Preview-5040100~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd 

Date/Time:     
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          5477589 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           109
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  4115428 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   33
Anonymous UUID:                     

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89ede469 add_triangle + 24
1   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89ede77c CGTriangleMeshAddTriangle + 61
2   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89ea241f type4_read_triangle + 246
3   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89ea264a cg_shading_type4_draw + 397
4   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89edc151 CGShadingDelegateDrawShading + 298
5   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00007fff8a7672af ripc_DrawShading + 7747
6   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89d163c9 CGContextDrawShading + 84
7   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89eae6a6 CGPatternDelegateDrawPattern + 160
8   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00007fff8a764391 ripc_TilePattern + 5213
9   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00007fff8a74a4db ripc_GetColor + 3141
10  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00007fff8a748d2d ripc_Render + 210
11  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00007fff8a764e42 ripc_DrawPath + 678
12  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89d415cf CGContextDrawPath + 160
13  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89d5ca2f CGPDFDrawingContextDrawPath + 162
14  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89d5c3da pdf_scanner_handle_xname + 105
15  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89d5b79b CGPDFScannerScan + 472
16  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89e948cd CGPDFDrawingContextDraw + 85
17  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89e94cdd CGPDFDrawingContextDrawStream + 83
18  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89e99c2b CGPDFDrawingContextDrawForm + 316
19  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89e95882 op_Do + 122
20  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89d5c3da pdf_scanner_handle_xname + 105
21  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89d5b79b CGPDFScannerScan + 472
22  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89d59850 CGPDFDrawingContextDrawPage + 787
23  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff89d594ee CGContextDrawPDFPageWithProgressCallback + 100
24  com.apple.PDFKit                0x00007fff8936515f -[PDFPage(PDFPagePrivate) drawWithBox:inContext:] + 629
25  com.apple.PDFKit                0x00007fff8934d17c -[PDFView drawPage:] + 193
26  com.apple.Preview               0x000000010005717e -[PVPDFView drawPage:] + 546
27  com.apple.PDFKit                0x00007fff893418e9 -[PDFDisplayView drawPDFHighLevel:] + 137
28  com.apple.PDFKit                0x00007fff893417d7 -[PDFDisplayView drawRect:] + 594
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82a86d75 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3566
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82a8454b -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 2112
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82a84ed6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82a84ed6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82a803de -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2683
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff829f9c0e -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 969
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82ac87f7 -[NSClipView _immediateScrollToPoint:] + 3886
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82ac7841 -[NSClipView scrollToPoint:] + 229
37  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b0494e -[NSScrollView scrollClipView:toPoint:] + 350
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82a427f8 -[NSClipView _scrollTo:animate:] + 1121
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b1f3ab -[NSScrollView _doScroller:hitPart:multiplier:] + 987
40  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b1eeda -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 95
41  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b1ee39 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 94
42  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b1edc4 -[NSScroller sendAction:to:] + 85
43  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b1ebd3 -[NSScroller(NSScrollerPrivate) _scrollByDelta:] + 973
44  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b1e26f -[NSScrollView scrollWheel:] + 815
45  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff829f6206 forwardMethod + 104
46  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b1df12 -[NSView scrollWheel:] + 228
47  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff829f6206 forwardMethod + 104
48  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b1df12 -[NSView scrollWheel:] + 228
49  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff829f6206 forwardMethod + 104
50  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82b1df12 -[NSView scrollWheel:] + 228
51  com.apple.PDFKit                0x00007fff89341555 -[PDFDisplayView scrollWheel:] + 711
52  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82ac40c7 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 8769
53  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff829f8afa -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4719
54  com.apple.Preview               0x000000010000290c -[PVApplication sendEvent:] + 357
55  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8298f6de -[NSApplication run] + 474
56  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff829883b0 NSApplicationMain + 364
57  com.apple.Preview               0x0000000100001454 start + 52

Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM MBP71.0039.B0B, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.62f6
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
```